# Curvature tensor of interpolation of two metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, geometric-structures

Let $\hat{g}$ and $\bar{g}$ be two smooth Riemannian metrics defined, say, on $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Consider a smooth function $\xi$ that acts as an interpolation function between the two metrics above on an annulus $B_{2R}(0)\backslash B_R(0).$

If we define $g=\xi\hat{g} + (1-\xi)\bar{g},$ which is clearly a smooth Riemannian metric, can we find write $Rm(g)$ in terms of $Rm(\hat{g})$ and $Rm(\bar{g})$ plus an error? More importantly, what would be the structure of this error?

I am sure someone did this calculation already, but I cannot find it anywhere. The calculation gets very messy very quickly, so I would appreciate a reference if anyone has one. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is, I think, about the paths geometry of the space of metrics. If so, I think, you can look at the work of Cheeger-Ebin.

Comment: Sorry, it's instead: DAVID G. EBIN and JERROLD MARSDEN "Groups of diffeomorphisms and the motion of an incompressible fluid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some Googling, the trick seems to be to consider the difference between the two metrics $ h = \tilde{g}-\bar{g}.$ Thus, $g= \bar{g} + \xi h.$ Using the notation above, we can write the Christoffel symbols of $g$ schematically as:

$\Gamma(g) = \Gamma(\bar{g}) + \frac{1}{2}g * \bar{\nabla}(\xi h),$

where $ h = \tilde{g}-\bar{g}.$ Thus,

$Rm(g)= Rm(\bar{g}) + g^{-1} *[ \bar{\nabla}^2\xi *h + \bar{\nabla}\xi*\bar{\nabla}h+ \xi^2\bar{\nabla}^2h] + g^{-2}[*\bar{\nabla}\xi*\bar{\nabla}\xi*h*h + \bar{\nabla}h*\bar{\nabla}\xi*\xi h +\xi^2*\bar{\nabla}h*\bar{\nabla}h],$

where $A*B$ denotes any linear combination of terms involving contractions of the tensor product $A\otimes B.$

The details can be found in this paper by Gursky and Viaclovsky: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870815301596?via%3Dihub.